# Conditions are equivalent: exist holomorphic function and path contractible to point

Tags: complex-analysis

> Not empty set $U \subset \mathbb{C} \backslash\{0\}$ is Domain. Prove
>   that these conditions are equivalent:
>
> 1. exist holomorphic function $g: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such, that $\forall_{z \in U} e^{g(z)}=z$
> 2. every path $\gamma$ which is $\mathcal{C}^{1}$ and values in set $U$ is in set $\mathbb{C} \backslash\{0\}$ contractible to a point (i.e.
>      is in $\mathbb{C} \backslash\{0\}$ homotopic to a constant).

How to show this? 
Do you have a hint?

Comment: This is a basic theorem in Complex Analysis. A good reference is Rudin's RCA.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Where it is?

Comment: Just look for homotopy in the index. Also there is a theorem which gives a number of equivalent conditions for a region to be simply connected. Your result is part of that theorem. Since I have an Asian edition of the book I cannot give you the exact reference.